# Using two hazard ratios to make third comparison

Tags: hazard

I have two sets of hazard ratios (with confidence intervals), one comparing risk of developing a cancer between current smokers and never smokers, and another comparing former smokers to never smokers. I do not have the raw data. Is there a way to use this information to create a hazard ratio comparing current smokers and former smokers?

For example, the hazard ratio for current smokers vs never smokers is 2.0 [95% CI, 1.2-3.4], and the ratio between former smokers and never smokers is 1.5 [95% CI, 0.9-2.5]. Is it possible to calculate a ratio for current vs former, with a 95% CI?

Thanks!